# Why isn't the date visible on the top bar?

Tags: indicator, gnome-shell, date, clock

The day of the week time is displayed on the top bar...
Why isn't the date displayed there, like it was in previous versions???
Why on earth would this capability have been removed???

Comment: Which version do you have?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? After a fresh install, you should install Gnome Tweaks and from it, you can tweak the date and more.

Comment: I have just upgraded to ubuntu 18.04...   I found somewhere else someone recommended   I use dconf to customize the TopBar, and that seemed to work fine..    or would Gnome-Tweak-Tool be a better solution?

Comment: @MattB No, they do the same thing. Tweaks is less advanced, but more user-friendly imo (so you're unlikely to mess things up with Tweaks unlike dconf editor).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to Ubuntu 18.04...
... the format of the "top bar" is controlled by "Gnome Tweaks".

Install it, Start it, then you will find "top bar" configurations for enabling

- Battery Percentage
- Date
- Seconds
- Calendar weeks

Comment: I used dconf, and that seemed to work for what I wanted to do.  Would Gnome Tweaks be better?

Comment: (Again assuming you refer to Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10), the man page for gnome-control-center (what is invoked when you go into "settings" (the tool icon)), says the following about your followup question:  
"Note that gnome-control-center is not meant to expose each and every setting that is available. The settings that can be found here represent what is considered useful and commonly needed options. For more exotic or uncommon options, you can look at  gnome-tweak-tool or the gsettings commandline utility."